# How do i share profile user fields in multisite?

Tags: users, multi-sites

I am trying to share user profile fields in a multi-site. In the settings.php I tried like this for users and its sharing the common users fields.

```
$databases = array (
        'default' =>
        array (
                'default' =>
                array (
                        'database' => 'db',
                        'username' => 'root',
                        'password' => 'password',
                        'host' => '170.10.40.150',
                        'port' => '',
                        'driver' => 'mysql',
                        //'prefix' => 'main_',
                        'prefix' => array(
                            'default'   => 'go_',
                            'users'     => 'main_',
                            'sessions'  => 'main_',
                            'role'      => 'main_',
                            'authmap'   => 'main_',
                        ),
                ),
        ),
);
```

Like wise if i try for user profile fields its not working.

```
$databases = array (
        'default' =>
        array (
                'default' =>
                array (
                        'database' => 'db',
                        'username' => 'root',
                        'password' => 'password',
                        'host' => '170.10.40.150',
                        'port' => '',
                        'driver' => 'mysql',
                        //'prefix' => 'main_',
                        'prefix' => array(
                            'default'   => 'go_',
                            'users'     => 'main_',
                            'sessions'  => 'main_',
                            'role'      => 'main_',
                            'authmap'   => 'main_',
                        'field_data_field_name_first' => 'main_',
                        'field_revision_field_name_first' => 'main_',
                        'field_data_field_generic_name' => 'main_',
                        'field_revision_field_generic_name' => 'main_'
                        ),
                ),
        ),
);
```

Any help will be really appreciated in knowing how to share profile user fields or what i am doing wrong.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**First:** remove from `settings.php`:

```
'field_data_field_name_first' => 'main_',
'field_revision_field_name_first' => 'main_',
'field_data_field_generic_name' => 'main_',
'field_revision_field_generic_name' => 'main_'
```

**Second:** create those fields in every site that will share them and attach them to user entities.

**Third:** Add again to `settings.php`:

```
'field_data_field_name_first' => 'main_',
'field_revision_field_name_first' => 'main_',
'field_data_field_generic_name' => 'main_',
'field_revision_field_generic_name' => 'main_'
```